# Ionic Cordova Camera not working

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using exactly the following [Git (see here the code)](https://github.com/sibizavic/phonegapcam01) as an input for Phonegap Build and have installed the app on my phone correctly (iOS).

The app opens correctly but when I try to take a picture (clicking on the button) nothing happens. It should display the image that was taken by the camera.

Can someone explain to me what is not working? The tutorial is from the Ionic website.

Alternative: does someone have a working .git or code for phonegap?

Comment: Does this work for you?: https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/use-android-ios-camera-ionic-framework/

Comment: Do you have a git link so I can directly test it on Phonegap Build?

Comment: Btw, can you clarify "Remember that you must be using a Mac if you wish to build for iOS" - does this mean only the testing part, thus using Phonegap Build will still work for iOS if I just prepare the code properly

Comment: You cannot build iOS or test iOS applications on a Windows or Linux computer.  You must use a Mac to do this.  I don't use Phonegap Build, so I can't really advise on that.  Go through the tutorial, and if you run into specific problems, I'm happy to help :)

Comment: Hello Nic, great tutorial and blog (have favorited it). I just went  through the tutorial and installed it using Phonegap Build on my phone but it still does not work (clicking shows no event). Do you know the cause or what other ways could I try to install it on my phone (I guess this would not make a difference, but just to be sure)? I use iOS8

Comment: Btw, you can find the git I used for the Phonegap Build here: https://github.com/sibizavic/nicraboy

Comment: Personal friends of mine had poor experiences with cloud building solutions which I think Phonegap Build is.  The best way to develop and test Cordova apps for iOS is to use a Mac with XCode.

Comment: I'll try your GitHub code tomorrow when I'm at my Mac.

Comment: FYI, I tried again today with some modifications to my config.xml. The code is available here: https://github.com/sibizavic/phonegapcam01

Comment: Hi, I tested the sample nicraboy repository you made with my iPod Touch 8.0.2 and it worked without issue.  The app was built using `ionic build ios` and then installed via XCode.  I still think your issue resides with your cloud building solution.

Comment: Thanks for testing it out. I figured everything out now. Basically, if you are developing in a cloud environment and dont have a mac, you can still do it. I have answered my question (you can use it if you ever want to write a tutorial on your website). The ionic build ios is only needed if you are testing it locally or in a simulator. Phonegap Build actually builds everything for you (so no need of building), as long as you have a config.xml file in your /www directory next to your index.html. My mistake was that this file was wrong, I have updated the right one below in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @AMG The Git link is not working, please update latest one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oke so I figured it out, its all about setting up config.xml properly!

Here is an overview how to build a sample camera app with Ionic and Phonegap Build

**1. Install NodeJS or go to c9.io (Cloud Environment) and start a NodeJs project. Delete all files if needed**

**2. Install Ionic and start a project (here: tabs)**

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
ionic start myApp tabs
```

**2a. cd myApp**

**2b. optional, add the plugin (if testing in browser or on your simulator)**

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

**3. cd www**

**4. Install through Bower or Unzip ngCordova in /lib**

```
bower install ngCordova
```

**5. Add the ngCordova reference in index.html**

In index.html add

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
```

before

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

**6. in app.js add 'ngCordova' as dependency**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCordova'])
```

**7. Write the controller**

```
.controller("ExampleCtrl", function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {

    $scope.takePicture = function() {
        var options = { 
            quality : 75, 
            destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, 
            sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
            allowEdit : true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 300,
            targetHeight: 300,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
            $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }, function(err) {
            // An error occured. Show a message to the user
        });
    }

});
```

**8. Use the controller in .html (don't forget to add a state tab.example with ExampleCtrl in app.js)**

```
<ion-view view-title="Example">
  <ion-content>
    <img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}">
    <img ng-show="imgURI === undefined" ng-src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    <button class="button" ng-click="takePicture()">Take Picture</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**9. Add the proper config.xml. Use this template:**

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/config.xml

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)

Comment: 1 thing though - 
"3. cd www

4. Install through Bower or Unzip ngCordova in /lib

bower install ngCordova" - .bowerecc file already takes care of the bower files to place them directly under /www/lib .. so we don't need to cd into www ..

Comment: Can you elaborate step number 9. Where to add config.xml or what to do with it?

Comment: That config.xml won't run.  It also needs a <content src='index.html'>

Comment: Options : cameraDirection : 1 [ front camera = 1 ] and allowEdit : true for camera taken pic is not working.

Comment: @DineshDevkota you need to add the camera to the the config.xml `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" />`