# ngCamera not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, cordova

I have been trying to get my camera to work on iOS for a couple days now. I found this [Ionic Cordova Camera not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27845345/ionic-cordova-camera-not-working), but when I get to the part that says to put this into the command line "cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera" it returns this error "Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/org.apache.cordova.camera" I tried finding why it was returning that error but can't find a good response.

I also did the add  before  and still nothing.

**EDIT** I was able to do a little more digging and found an error "Error: Can't find variable: Camera"

I should add that this works just fine on android but iOS wants nothing to do with the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run below command in your working directory. That will add camera plugin in your projects.--save flag will save your plugin in config.xml file.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --save
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```